# One form with multiple inputs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the following form in my View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Listing',array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->select('',array('0'=>'Τα καλύτερα','1'=>'Οι καλύτεροι','2'=>'Οι καλύτερες'));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Item.content.'.($i+1),array('label'=>'Προσθήκη αντικιμένου'));
}
echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file','label'=>'Φωτογραφία:'));
echo $this->Form->input('description', array('rows' => '4','label'=>'Περιγραφή:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Αποθήκευση Λίστας');
```

The controller has the following code:

```
public function add() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Listing->Save($this->request->data)) {

                $this->request->data['Item']['listing_id'] = $this->Listing->id;
                $this->Listing->Item->save($this->request->data);   
                $this->Session->setFlash('Η λίστα αποθηκεύτηκε');   
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Αδύνατη η αποθήκευση της λίστας.');
            }
        }   
}
```

The above controller works if I have one `input` for content in the form, but if I use the `for` loop in the View for multiple `input` it doesn't works. How can I save the content of multiple `input` in  a associated table? I tried `saveMany()`, `saveAssociated()` & `saveAll()` but nothing worked, obviously I did something wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: Post the Form's HTML generated and the debug($this->request->data) that gets submitted.  This will help greatly in quickly determining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for statement to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Item.'. $i+1 .'.content', array('label'=>'Προσθήκη αντικιμένου'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Item.content.'.($i+1),array('name' => 'data[Item][content][]', 'label'=>'Προσθήκη αντικιμένου'));
}
```